# How to install the UI-theme in Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-shell, theme, icons

I want to install the theme (shell style + icons) to `Fedora 21`. In order to that, I installed the `Gnome Tweak Tool`. I tried to install themes (`Install Shell Extension`) from http://gnome-look.org/, but all themes I tried returned the error `Invalid extension`, probably, due to high Gnome version. Could you please explain where to get the themes for `Fedora 21` and how to install them. The real example is welcomed.

P.S. As far as I know, the themes are stored in `/usr/share/themes`, but when I tried to write to this folder I got access error, even when I tried to copy the folder in `Terminal` with `sudo`/`su` rights. How can I write to this folder or should I use another location, such as `/home/user/.theme`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install the [User Themes Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/). Having done that, you can unpack your downloaded themes into `~/.themes` (so that they end up in `~/.themes/ThemeName`, with the directory `gnome-shell` under that). *Then*, they'll show up in Gnome Tweak Tool. (You may have to restart the shell, with `ALT-F2`, a single `r` in the command dialog, and <enter>.)

Comment: I download the extension from https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions, according to the version of Gnome in my OS, but when I tried to install it I got the `Invalid extension` warning.

Comment: @MikeB Oh, actually, we have that one packaged up; you should be able to just `yum install gnome-shell-extension-user-theme`.